Stream data between main thread and webassembly worker thread in Browser
I have a website that would do video compression for users. It is implemented using ffmpeg webassembly tech in browser. However, due to the arraybuffer size limiation for browsers (link), especially Chrome, this tool cannot support input video size larger than 2GB.
I wonder if there is a way I could stream the video data from main thread to Webassembly worker thread such that I don't need to create an arraybuffer to pass the video data to worker thread? Is that possible with WASM tech?
